# MVC 5 Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, windows-authentication

I'm building an intranet application using MVC 5 and windows authentication.

Up until today everything was working as I'd expect:

- User was picked up under `User.Identity`
- `[Authorize]` attribute in controllers was working based on the user.

Web.config is set with `<authentication mode="Windows"/>` and the appropriate  `<system.webServer>  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">` to allow for custom auth error display.  IIS Express is set for `Windows Authentication enabled` and `Anonynous Authentication Enabled` as needed for the custom auth errors.

As of this morning no user being picked up, which means that the Authorized controllers are going to the custom error page.  I also have the user displayed in the header as per the base MVC template which is currently displaying blank.

The only change I've made was to downgrade the project from `4.5.2` to `4.5` but reversing this doesn't make any difference.

If I disable anon auth I get a basic auth prompt on the home page which has no  `Authorize` attribute.  This is leading me to think there's an issue establishing the user from the system.  Is there anyway I can test this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you make any progress?  What things are you finding / researching?

Comment: @TomStickel No progress but have mainly been on a different project.  The thing that threw me the most was the fact it used to work, now doesn't.  Could be domain related I suppose, will test again soon.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with me overriding <httpErrors> in the system.webServer section of the web.config.  I was taking over the 401 for clean auth errors which seems to be killing the auth completely.